# How do you append to a file in ClojureScript (on Node)?

Tags: clojurescript, clojurescript-javascript-interop

How can you append to a local file using ClojureScript (running on Node)?

Answer (score 2):

Use the Node.js `fs.appendFileSync` method from the `fs` package, like so:

```clj
(.appendFileSync fs "/path/to/file.txt" "string to append")
```

This will also create the file if it doesn't exist yet.